# R matrix: How can I subset based on the sum across all columns?

Tags: r, subset, rows

I have a very large matrix, >30,000 elements. I would like to remove all rows that have a value of 0 across all column. After reading many posts, I think that parameters such as standard deviation=0 or the sum of the rows=0 would be appropriate to drop. I can't seem to figure out a working R code to do this. The subset command makes sense... I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Another approach that may work:

I ran `as.logical(rowSums(matrix !=0))` to return all of the rows that had values that were not 0, which worked. Is there another line that I can add in to create a new matrix with just the rows that returned `TRUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix, create a logical `vector` and subset the rows of the `matrix`

```
m2 <- m1[!!rowSums(m1 != 0),]
```

#### data

```
m1 <- rbind(0, c(1, 3, 2), c(0, 1,2), c(4, 5, 2))
```

Comment: what do are values in the c( )?

Comment: @Emily It is just creating a reproducible example for testing

Comment: @ akrun yes, this returns a matrix and your first code does eliminate the first row with all zeros. This is what I need, but for my matrix it did not work.

Comment: @Emily Without a small reproducible example, it is not clear to me about the structure of your data etc.

Comment: @Emily Your new condition is `> 1` That means, it is looking for values above 1.  I assume that you don't have a value 0 in your dataset

Comment: values over 1 are fine for what I need. Even, >.01 works. Thank you so much for your help!